# Can I lock the root account during an install of Debian GNU/Linux 6 "squeeze"?

Tags: linux, debian, security, root

By default, Ubuntu [locks](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo) account root; can I do the same, in Debian GNU/Linux 6 "squeeze", during install?

Comment: During install I don't know, but just install Sudo after your install is complete. That's how I do with Arch for example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. When prompted to enter in a password for root, if left blank, debian will lock root and add the user you created to the `wheel` group so you can use sudo.